# DataFrame complex json dictionary

Tags: python, arrays, json, python-3.x, pandas

My json is formated this way:

A json sample (only one response):

```
[{"FaceDetails": [{"BoundingBox": {"Width": 0.20645833015441895, "Height": 0.34566667675971985, "Left": 0.1320784091949463, "Top": 0.2870468497276306}, "AgeRange": {"Low": 35, "High": 52}, "Smile": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 86.16860961914062}, "Eyeglasses": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 99.21920013427734}, "Sunglasses": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 99.35169982910156}, "Gender": {"Value": "Male", "Confidence": 98.19034576416016}, "Beard": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 94.8172607421875}, "Mustache": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 98.80828094482422}, "EyesOpen": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 99.99850463867188}, "MouthOpen": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 84.43124389648438}, "Emotions": [{"Type": "HAPPY", "Confidence": 6.950818061828613}, {"Type": "ANGRY", "Confidence": 8.036457061767578}, {"Type": "CONFUSED", "Confidence": 30.87822151184082}, {"Type": "CALM", "Confidence": 36.122955322265625}, {"Type": "SURPRISED", "Confidence": 5.876465320587158}, {"Type": "SAD", "Confidence": 9.060415267944336}, {"Type": "DISGUSTED", "Confidence": 3.074671745300293}], "Landmarks": [{"Type": "eyeLeft", "X": 0.20133039355278015, "Y": 0.4523984491825104}, {"Type": "eyeRight", "X": 0.28129422664642334, "Y": 0.4087912440299988}, {"Type": "mouthLeft", "X": 0.24184171855449677, "Y": 0.5613872408866882}, {"Type": "mouthRight", "X": 0.3082438111305237, "Y": 0.5248567461967468}, {"Type": "nose", "X": 0.269692063331604, "Y": 0.49691712856292725}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowLeft", "X": 0.15909677743911743, "Y": 0.44103655219078064}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowRight", "X": 0.21194136142730713, "Y": 0.4123869240283966}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowUp", "X": 0.1844387650489807, "Y": 0.4178501069545746}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowLeft", "X": 0.25881028175354004, "Y": 0.3871847689151764}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowRight", "X": 0.3012760579586029, "Y": 0.3637477457523346}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowUp", "X": 0.2788476049900055, "Y": 0.36720070242881775}, {"Type": "leftEyeLeft", "X": 0.1855049878358841, "Y": 0.4580109119415283}, {"Type": "leftEyeRight", "X": 0.21691501140594482, "Y": 0.44434690475463867}, {"Type": "leftEyeUp", "X": 0.19991904497146606, "Y": 0.44687533378601074}, {"Type": "leftEyeDown", "X": 0.2031686156988144, "Y": 0.4566645622253418}, {"Type": "rightEyeLeft", "X": 0.2643232047557831, "Y": 0.41856878995895386}, {"Type": "rightEyeRight", "X": 0.2917978763580322, "Y": 0.4000416100025177}, {"Type": "rightEyeUp", "X": 0.2787345349788666, "Y": 0.4039233922958374}, {"Type": "rightEyeDown", "X": 0.2809092402458191, "Y": 0.41421836614608765}, {"Type": "noseLeft", "X": 0.25243401527404785, "Y": 0.5145910382270813}, {"Type": "noseRight", "X": 0.28085580468177795, "Y": 0.4972332715988159}, {"Type": "mouthUp", "X": 0.27561885118484497, "Y": 0.5329715609550476}, {"Type": "mouthDown", "X": 0.28394615650177, "Y": 0.5653430223464966}, {"Type": "leftPupil", "X": 0.20133039355278015, "Y": 0.4523984491825104}, {"Type": "rightPupil", "X": 0.28129422664642334, "Y": 0.4087912440299988}, {"Type": "upperJawlineLeft", "X": 0.1311698704957962, "Y": 0.46898868680000305}, {"Type": "midJawlineLeft", "X": 0.18856483697891235, "Y": 0.5825732350349426}, {"Type": "chinBottom", "X": 0.2962130606174469, "Y": 0.6203031539916992}, {"Type": "midJawlineRight", "X": 0.33180156350135803, "Y": 0.5042592883110046}, {"Type": "upperJawlineRight", "X": 0.30957236886024475, "Y": 0.37158241868019104}], "Pose": {"Roll": -23.102828979492188, "Yaw": 3.1219544410705566, "Pitch": -3.5442771911621094}, "Quality": {"Brightness": 76.52424621582031, "Sharpness": 96.61495208740234}, "Confidence": 99.99998474121094}, {"BoundingBox": {"Width": 0.1537969559431076, "Height": 0.27064284682273865, "Left": 0.700599193572998, "Top": 0.17026177048683167}, "AgeRange": {"Low": 48, "High": 68}, "Smile": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 76.73896789550781}, "Eyeglasses": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 88.32019805908203}, "Sunglasses": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 97.24940490722656}, "Gender": {"Value": "Male", "Confidence": 99.2653579711914}, "Beard": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 87.09922790527344}, "Mustache": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 99.34098815917969}, "EyesOpen": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 99.93042755126953}, "MouthOpen": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 83.3313980102539}, "Emotions": [{"Type": "DISGUSTED", "Confidence": 2.652924060821533}, {"Type": "CALM", "Confidence": 9.28744125366211}, {"Type": "SAD", "Confidence": 3.2358903884887695}, {"Type": "SURPRISED", "Confidence": 7.827535152435303}, {"Type": "HAPPY", "Confidence": 69.06285095214844}, {"Type": "CONFUSED", "Confidence": 5.798086643218994}, {"Type": "ANGRY", "Confidence": 2.135272741317749}], "Landmarks": [{"Type": "eyeLeft", "X": 0.7253099679946899, "Y": 0.2848934233188629}, {"Type": "eyeRight", "X": 0.7882346510887146, "Y": 0.26943516731262207}, {"Type": "mouthLeft", "X": 0.7452651262283325, "Y": 0.3746360242366791}, {"Type": "mouthRight", "X": 0.7972681522369385, "Y": 0.3620894253253937}, {"Type": "nose", "X": 0.7582045197486877, "Y": 0.3277147710323334}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowLeft", "X": 0.7002695202827454, "Y": 0.26892876625061035}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowRight", "X": 0.7316190004348755, "Y": 0.25571879744529724}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowUp", "X": 0.714163601398468, "Y": 0.25501909852027893}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowLeft", "X": 0.7685369253158569, "Y": 0.24632084369659424}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowRight", "X": 0.812128484249115, "Y": 0.2415061891078949}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowUp", "X": 0.787868857383728, "Y": 0.23653507232666016}, {"Type": "leftEyeLeft", "X": 0.7158089876174927, "Y": 0.2861402630805969}, {"Type": "leftEyeRight", "X": 0.7383458614349365, "Y": 0.281990110874176}, {"Type": "leftEyeUp", "X": 0.7247799038887024, "Y": 0.28006812930107117}, {"Type": "leftEyeDown", "X": 0.7267125844955444, "Y": 0.2880774736404419}, {"Type": "rightEyeLeft", "X": 0.7757328748703003, "Y": 0.27263185381889343}, {"Type": "rightEyeRight", "X": 0.7996259331703186, "Y": 0.2653029263019562}, {"Type": "rightEyeUp", "X": 0.7869282960891724, "Y": 0.26458436250686646}, {"Type": "rightEyeDown", "X": 0.7880036234855652, "Y": 0.2728675901889801}, {"Type": "noseLeft", "X": 0.7515624761581421, "Y": 0.3401409983634949}, {"Type": "noseRight", "X": 0.7753664255142212, "Y": 0.3328358829021454}, {"Type": "mouthUp", "X": 0.7662389278411865, "Y": 0.35781601071357727}, {"Type": "mouthDown", "X": 0.7714887857437134, "Y": 0.3842341899871826}, {"Type": "leftPupil", "X": 0.7253099679946899, "Y": 0.2848934233188629}, {"Type": "rightPupil", "X": 0.7882346510887146, "Y": 0.26943516731262207}, {"Type": "upperJawlineLeft", "X": 0.6985645890235901, "Y": 0.2904370427131653}, {"Type": "midJawlineLeft", "X": 0.7255792617797852, "Y": 0.38543701171875}, {"Type": "chinBottom", "X": 0.7816726565361023, "Y": 0.4296976625919342}, {"Type": "midJawlineRight", "X": 0.8388493061065674, "Y": 0.3573923707008362}, {"Type": "upperJawlineRight", "X": 0.8395764827728271, "Y": 0.2554771900177002}], "Pose": {"Roll": -15.45954704284668, "Yaw": -22.94147300720215, "Pitch": 1.8358955383300781}, "Quality": {"Brightness": 81.80601501464844, "Sharpness": 67.22731018066406}, "Confidence": 100.0}, {"BoundingBox": {"Width": 0.1318165361881256, "Height": 0.2411908209323883, "Left": 0.3859011232852936, "Top": 0.23061266541481018}, "AgeRange": {"Low": 35, "High": 52}, "Smile": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 95.98809814453125}, "Eyeglasses": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 99.22638702392578}, "Sunglasses": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 99.9509048461914}, "Gender": {"Value": "Male", "Confidence": 99.8205795288086}, "Beard": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 99.55491638183594}, "Mustache": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 99.98772430419922}, "EyesOpen": {"Value": true, "Confidence": 99.98260498046875}, "MouthOpen": {"Value": false, "Confidence": 97.35255432128906}, "Emotions": [{"Type": "HAPPY", "Confidence": 65.48389434814453}, {"Type": "ANGRY", "Confidence": 1.8191800117492676}, {"Type": "CONFUSED", "Confidence": 1.5404573678970337}, {"Type": "CALM", "Confidence": 22.578277587890625}, {"Type": "SURPRISED", "Confidence": 1.6822370290756226}, {"Type": "SAD", "Confidence": 1.8240364789962769}, {"Type": "DISGUSTED", "Confidence": 5.071920394897461}], "Landmarks": [{"Type": "eyeLeft", "X": 0.41944846510887146, "Y": 0.3230561912059784}, {"Type": "eyeRight", "X": 0.4784352481365204, "Y": 0.3221887946128845}, {"Type": "mouthLeft", "X": 0.42567890882492065, "Y": 0.4034501314163208}, {"Type": "mouthRight", "X": 0.4747196137905121, "Y": 0.40266478061676025}, {"Type": "nose", "X": 0.45356547832489014, "Y": 0.36987295746803284}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowLeft", "X": 0.3953215479850769, "Y": 0.3032199442386627}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowRight", "X": 0.43288755416870117, "Y": 0.3006165623664856}, {"Type": "leftEyeBrowUp", "X": 0.4148208498954773, "Y": 0.29563677310943604}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowLeft", "X": 0.4674118459224701, "Y": 0.3002321422100067}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowRight", "X": 0.4999593496322632, "Y": 0.301784873008728}, {"Type": "rightEyeBrowUp", "X": 0.4841403067111969, "Y": 0.2949654757976532}, {"Type": "leftEyeLeft", "X": 0.408809095621109, "Y": 0.321848601102829}, {"Type": "leftEyeRight", "X": 0.4310573935508728, "Y": 0.32314229011535645}, {"Type": "leftEyeUp", "X": 0.4196675717830658, "Y": 0.319062739610672}, {"Type": "leftEyeDown", "X": 0.4200402796268463, "Y": 0.32627660036087036}, {"Type": "rightEyeLeft", "X": 0.46596455574035645, "Y": 0.32256847620010376}, {"Type": "rightEyeRight", "X": 0.4870268702507019, "Y": 0.3204285204410553}, {"Type": "rightEyeUp", "X": 0.4776625633239746, "Y": 0.318028062582016}, {"Type": "rightEyeDown", "X": 0.4772416353225708, "Y": 0.3252185583114624}, {"Type": "noseLeft", "X": 0.44026610255241394, "Y": 0.3768109381198883}, {"Type": "noseRight", "X": 0.461662620306015, "Y": 0.3757146894931793}, {"Type": "mouthUp", "X": 0.451613187789917, "Y": 0.39584681391716003}, {"Type": "mouthDown", "X": 0.45127174258232117, "Y": 0.4191305339336395}, {"Type": "leftPupil", "X": 0.41944846510887146, "Y": 0.3230561912059784}, {"Type": "rightPupil", "X": 0.4784352481365204, "Y": 0.3221887946128845}, {"Type": "upperJawlineLeft", "X": 0.37512674927711487, "Y": 0.31603309512138367}, {"Type": "midJawlineLeft", "X": 0.3905247747898102, "Y": 0.40460944175720215}, {"Type": "chinBottom", "X": 0.44983744621276855, "Y": 0.4589351415634155}, {"Type": "midJawlineRight", "X": 0.4960060715675354, "Y": 0.4026068449020386}, {"Type": "upperJawlineRight", "X": 0.5064978003501892, "Y": 0.3135608434677124}], "Pose": {"Roll": -5.339792728424072, "Yaw": 9.509183883666992, "Pitch": -21.126737594604492}, "Quality": {"Brightness": 72.04667663574219, "Sharpness": 38.89601135253906}, "Confidence": 99.9999771118164}], "ResponseMetadata": {"RequestId": "9d3f8c87-3d01-11e9-9c40-e19b32f71e69", "HTTPStatusCode": 200, "HTTPHeaders": {"content-type": "application/x-amz-json-1.1", "date": "Sat, 02 Mar 2019 15:41:24 GMT", "x-amzn-requestid": "9d3f8c87-3d01-11e9-9c40-e19b32f71e69", "content-length": "9832", "connection": "keep-alive"}, "RetryAttempts": 0}}]
```

Each 'FaceDetails' object contains nested 'BoundingBox' objects. I need to dataframe the AgeRange and Gender for each object.

Can you please help me dtaframe this structure?

I have been working on this for the last couple of days. The code that displays what I want doesn't show it in dataframe:

```
from pandas.io.json import json_normalize
import csv


with open('face.json') as json_data:
    data = json.loads(json_data.read())
for d in data:
face_details = json_normalize(data=d['FaceDetails'], meta=['AgeRange', 'Gender'])
```

And this is the result:

[image]

Please Help.

Comment: Wow! I attempted to format your json with [jsonformatter](https://jsonformatter.curiousconcept.com) but result exceeds limit of 32K characters. Can you simplify your json? Or maybe add an explanation of json structure into your question?

Comment: I just added a sample- My json is an API request from AWS rekognition.. I only need the age and gender columns.